# Runtime Error Issues

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, runtime-error

Got a bit of code here thats giving me a runtime error that I cant seem to fix.  The function Length() calculates the cumulative distance between all the points in an array of points.  It uses a previously defined function Distance() that I know works perfectly.  Any pointers?

Here is my source code for the function:

```
template<typename Point>                //Length function
double PointArray<Point>::Length() const
{
    double total_length = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<Size(); i++)
    {
        total_length += (GetElement(i)).Distance(GetElement(i+1));
    }
    return total_length;
}
```

And here is my implementation:

```
cout<<"The Length of the Point Array is: "<<(*ptArray1).Length()<<endl;
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading elements that are beyond the end of the array.

```
for (int i=0; i<Size(); i++)
{
    total_length += (GetElement(i)).Distance(GetElement(i+1));
                                                      //^^^
}
```

One you reach the end of the `for` loop you read the last element and then calculate the distance from the next element - which is outside the bounds of the array . Your `for` loop should look something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<Size() - 1; i++)
{
    total_length += (GetElement(i)).Distance(GetElement(i+1));
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Never would have thought of that.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
template<typename Point>                //Length function
double PointArray<Point>::Length() const
{
    double total_length = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<Size()-1; i++)
    {               //^^^ otherwise, i+1 will be out of range
        total_length += (GetElement(i)).Distance(GetElement(i+1));
    }
    return total_length;
}
```